# Humanoid Robot Control and Interaction

Tags: nao

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi all,
I am trying to run Halit Bener SUAY's Nao demo. I have found that in step 3:
"roslaunch openni_camera openni_kinect.launch", the file "openni_kinect.launch" doesn't exist, but "openni_node.launch". Then I went through to step 6.
When running "rosmake nao_openni", I got the errors:

```
/opt/ros/diamondback/stacks/ros_comm/clients/cpp/roscpp_traits/include/ros/message_traits.h:121: error: ‘const struct std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >’ has no member named ‘__getMD5Sum’
```

and

```
/opt/ros/diamondback/stacks/ros_comm/clients/cpp/roscpp_traits/include/ros/message_traits.h:138: error: ‘const struct std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >’ has no member named ‘__getDataType’
```

Hope someone can help me with this.
Thank you very much.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11498/humanoid-robot-control-and-interaction/) by [chang](https://answers.ros.org/users/1137/chang/) on ROS Answers with karma: 36 on 2011-10-11

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [chang](https://answers.ros.org/users/1137/chang/) on 2011-10-16**:
both errors stemmed from the file teleop_nao_ni.cpp.
2 lines were commented out:
teleop_nao_ni.cpp:872:  //obj.m_speechPub.publish(naosay.data);
teleop_nao_ni.cpp:976:      //teleopNao.m_speechPub.p

**Comment by [chang](https://answers.ros.org/users/1137/chang/) on 2011-10-16**:
Problem solved in this way:

**Comment by [AHornung](https://answers.ros.org/users/141/ahornung/) on 2011-10-11**:
Is that the complete error output from running make (as it's a little short)? Could it be that you're mixing a diamondback and electric ROS system somehow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In order to get rid of the compilation errors, I adjusted the C++ code a bit:
both errors stemmed from the file nao_openni/src/teleop_nao_ni.cpp.
I commented out these 2 lines:

teleop_nao_ni.cpp:872:  //obj.m_speechPub.publish(naosay.data);
teleop_nao_ni.cpp:976:      //teleopNao.m_speechPub.publish(naosay.data);

after which I was able to run the command "rosmake nao_openni" without errors.
I assume that my changes in the source file will not have any effect on the behaviour of the nao, except that the nao will a little more silent.

---

Originally posted by [chang](https://answers.ros.org/users/1137/chang/) with karma: 36 on 2011-10-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1